# What will be the bandwidth required for streaming 640x480@30fps Video as UVC (USB Video Class)?

Tags: usb, video

Will USB 2.0 be enough for the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

An uncompressed video stream will require:

$$640\times480\times(3\times8\text{ bit})\times30\text{ fps} = 27.65\text{ MB/s}$$

This is close to the net data rate I often encountered (~30 MB/s) for USB 2.0 with 480 Mbit/s devices. There are some devices around which reach more (thanks to Marcus Müller). So an uncompressed stream should be doable.

But you can also have a compressed stream as UVC 1.5 supports various compression formats:

> Video stream formats like MPEG-2 TS, H.264, MPEG-4 SL, SMPTE VC1, VP8
>   and MJPEG

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class))

I don't know the bitrate for those streams, but seeing that you can get a full HD stream over a 16 Mbit/s link, it shouldn't be a problem at all to get a compressed stream over USB 2.0.

Comment: how is ~222 Mb/s close to 480 Mb/s?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have not encountered a USB 2.0 device which was able to transfer more than 30 MB/s.

Comment: let me calculate; 10 MS/s · (2 int/S) · 2B/int= 40 MB/s; yep, the USRP1 does more than 30 MB/s.

Comment: @MarcusMüller nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most UVC webcams do a higher resolution and still work over USB2. Do a minimum amount of market research!